# The equivalent of the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} =|x_n-n|$.

Tags: real-analysis

We have $x_{n+1} =|x_n-n|$,then $x_1 = |x_0|\Rightarrow x_n\ge 0,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

In order to find the equivalent of that sequence, we are going to discuss two cases either $x_n\ge n $ or $x_n\le n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  If $x_n\ge n$, this implies that $x_{n+1} = x_n-n $, then the sequence converges to a limit, $l\ge 0,$ but the problem when doing the telescpoic summation,we are giing to find that $x_n \sim \frac{n^2}2, n\rightarrow \infty$. I am not sure if I should follow this path to solve this problem, or I am totally wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the equivalent of a sequence"?

Comment: @PaulFrost, I believe he means the asymptotic behavior of the sequence

Comment: I mean if there exists a sequence $y_n$ such that $x_n/y_n\rightarrow 1 $ , its notation is $x_n\sim y_n$.